# Unsure about calculations and if statements in python

Tags: python, pandas

There are 2 things that i'm unsure of, and would greatly appreciate help!

1) What I'm trying to achieve is, for this value, to do the below calculations, and then add half of the previous value, to its current value.

```
value = 0.5*2*((p-MinL)/(MaxT-MinL)-0.5)+0.5*value_previous
```

2) How should I phrase my If statement to control `value` results? What i've written so far is:

```
if value > 0.9999:
   value = 0.9999
elif value < -0.9999:
   value = -0.9999
```

But this keeps returning me errors... `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

The full code that i've written so far is

```
def module1():
    df = pd.read_csv("test_file.csv", index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
    # The columns in there are 'Date', 'Top', 'Low', 'cost', 'volume'

    p = (df['Top'] + df['Low']) / 2
    MaxT = pd.rolling_max(p, window=10)
    MinL = pd.rolling_min(p, window=10)

    #Below is where I wish to put the `value` calculation, and if statements. but not sure how it should be structured.
    value = 0.5*2*((p-MinL)/(MaxT-MinL)-0.5)+0.5*value_previous

    if value > 0.9999:
       value = 0.9999
    elif value < -0.9999:
       value = -0.9999
```

Comment: Can you post full code, also I think you can just do `df['value'].clip(-0.9999, 0.9999)`, also the reason for the error is that you're trying to compare a scalar with array-like structure this becomes ambiguous as what if 1 or more are true, should this be true or false?

Comment: Sorry when you say `value`, do you mean `Value`?

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for helping me with this. I've added my full code and changed `Value` to `value`. But yeah, They both refer to the same thing. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: So does `value = value.clip(-0.9999, 0.9999)` work? or if this is a np array `value = np.clip(value, -0.9999, 0.9999)`

Comment: @EdChum let me get home tonight to give it a shot! Will comment again about it. :)

Comment: @EdChum Hey, it doesnt work. the clip function doesnt return me the results of -0.9999 or 0.9999. Is my question 1 done correctly?

Comment: I can't say as I don't have your data, you may need to investigate that line as `clip` does the correct thing

Comment: Sorry can't help there